# Magento 2 : Custom field data is not saving in product add edit

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, custom, admin-panel

Custom Field is showing in Product `add/edit` but data not saving. Here is my full code

> Vend\Customattrib\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customTab" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vend\Customattrib\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\NewField</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

> Vend\Customattrib\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\NewField.php

```
<?php
namespace Vend\Customattrib\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\MultiSelect;

class NewField extends AbstractModifier
{
    private $locator;


     public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }


    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                'custom_fieldset' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('Custom Section'),
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => 'data.product.custom_fieldset',
                                'collapsible' => true,
                                'sortOrder' => 200,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        'custom_field' => $this->getCustomField()
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        );
        return $meta;
    }

    public function getCustomField()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Select'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => 'custom_data_opt',
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                        'options' => $this->_getOptions(),
                        'visible' => true,
                        'disabled' => false,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function _getOptions()
    {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('custom_data');
        $sql    = "SELECT `id`, `opt_name` FROM ".$tableName." WHERE is_active = 1";
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        $options        =   array();
        $options[]  =   array('value' => '', 'label' => 'Select Option');
        if($result)
        {
            foreach($result as $r)
            {
                $id             = $r['id'];
                $opt_name       = $r['opt_name'];
                $options[]      =   array('value' => $id, 'label' => $opt_name);
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }

}
```